# Unable to access volume content using initContainers

Tags: kubernetes, docker-volume

I have a simple image (mdw:1.0.0) with some content in it:

```
FROM alpine:3.9
COPY /role /mdw
WORKDIR /mdw
```

I was expecting that my container 'nginx' would see the content of /mdw folder, but there is no file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: init-demo
spec:
 initContainers:
 - name: install
   image: mdw:1.0.0
   imagePullPolicy: Never
   volumeMounts:
   - name: workdir
     mountPath: "/mdw"
 containers:
 - name: nginx
   image: nginx
   volumeMounts:
   - name: workdir
     mountPath: /mdw
   command: ["ls", "-l", "/mdw"]
 volumes:
 - name: workdir
   emptyDir: {}
```

Do you know what is the reason and how to fix it ?

Thank you very much

Comment: I recently found a similar question like this. Please check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62105986/change-kubernetes-stroge-class-mounted-value-from-another-pod).

Comment: how do you know it doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When mounting volume if directory already exists will get wiped. It's intentional and no fix really.

Only way would be to populate the directory after mounting is done.

Answer (score 1):

Your init container doesn't do anything: the Dockerfile doesn't have a `CMD` and the Kubernetes deployment spec doesn't set a `command:` either.  It starts and immediately exits.  (The base Linux distribution images generally have a default command to launch an interactive shell, but absent a tty this will also immediately exit.)

Meanwhile, your Kubernetes setup is also mounting an empty directory over the only content you've put into the image, which prevents the init container from having an effect.

You can build a custom `nginx` image that directly copies the content in:

```
FROM nginx
COPY /role /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Don't use `initContainers:`, and use that image as the main `containers:` image.

There is a Docker-specific feature, using Docker named volumes, that can populate a named volume on first use, and you're probably thinking of this feature.  This comes with a couple of important caveats (it only takes effect the very first time you run a container, and ignores updates to the image; it doesn't work with bind mounts).  This is a plain-Docker-specific feature: Kubernetes will never auto-populate a volume for you.

Comment: Thanks David for your reply. However, I am using initContainers because I wanted to separate the configuration templates (mdw), and the main application. The goal was to have: 1 container containing templates only. 1 container to run a templating engine and generate the final configuration for the main container. What you are proposing is to embed the configuration directly into the main application which I wanted to avoid. Do you understand what I mean ?

Comment: Is this things like an nginx configuration, or the actual HTML content?  I'd do things like render templates at build time, not deploy time (so more involved `RUN` commands in the Dockerfile); or use a Kubernetes ConfigMap to inject things like config files.

Comment: I would like to use the same image for all environments. I thought it would be a good practice to generate configuration at runtime. Building an image for each environment seems to be an anti-pattern